# MVC routing issue which I can't find a solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an Area called User. Under that area I have a view called Index.

Area Registration with only one route:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
context.MapRoute(
                "0",
                "user/signup",
                new { action = "Index", controller = "Signup" },
                new string[] { "Company.Web.Areas.User.Controllers" }
            );
}
```

Path to controller:

```
Areas\User\Controllers\SignupController.cs
```

Path to view:

```
Areas\User\Views\Signup\Index.cshtml
```

This is how I am trying to generate URL in header with Signup hyperlink:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Signup", new { area = "User", returnUrl=ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery })">Signup</a>
```

This is the url I am getting:
http://www.myserver.com/user/signup?returnUrl=home/main

The url looks correct, the routing has just one route.

But when I click the url it says: The resource cannot be found. user/signup

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
context.MapRoute(
            "signup",
            "{controller}/{action}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Signup", action = "Index" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

That should map to the Signup controller and the Index action